# Read-only SettableFuture reference

Tags: java, guava

Say an API method returns `ListenableFuture<T>`, and the return value is implemented as `SettableFuture<T>`.  Is there a way to return a 'ListenableFuture` that can't be cast back to a SettableFuture and completed by a misbehaving client?

So, a read-only view of the ListenableFuture.  Similar to wrapping a collection with `.unmodifiableCollection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably:

`return Futures.transform(future, x -> x);`

Note that that future is still "writable" in the sense that people can `cancel` it. If you want to prevent users from even cancelling the original future -- I don't think you care about this, but I wanted to be be bring it up anyway, since you said "read-only" -- then you can use:

`return Futures.nonCancellationPropagating(future);`

Comment: Now that you mention it, yes, I care about cancellation as well! Writing a failing test now. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

A well-spread design pattern to achieve this is the decorator pattern.
It could be worth having a look at how Guava's authors designed what they called a *forwarding future* for this type of requirement.

Here is for instance some code extracted from the abstract class [`ForwardingListenableFuture`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ForwardingListenableFuture.java):

```
/**
 * A {@link ListenableFuture} which forwards all its method calls to another
 * future. Subclasses should override one or more methods to modify the behavior
 * of the backing future as desired per the <a
 * href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern">decorator pattern</a>.
 *
 * <p>Most subclasses can just use {@link SimpleForwardingListenableFuture}.
 *
 * @param <V> The result type returned by this Future's {@code get} method
 * 
 * @author Shardul Deo
 * @since 4.0
 */
public abstract class ForwardingListenableFuture<V> extends ForwardingFuture<V> implements ListenableFuture<V> {

  /** Constructor for use by subclasses. */
  protected ForwardingListenableFuture() {}

  @Override
  protected abstract ListenableFuture<V> delegate();

  @Override
  public void addListener(Runnable listener, Executor exec) {
    delegate().addListener(listener, exec);
  }
  ...
```

As you can, the responsibility of this class is to wrap a `ListenableFuture` and hide its actual implementation to the client - both final users and implementors, as we can see the `delegate()` method returns a `ListenableFuture` instead of a concrete type.

The code which actually *creates* the `ListenableFuture` object which implementation you wish to hide needs to wraps or "decorates" it with an implementation of `ForwardingListenableFuture`, which will prevent clients to call `set` on the wrapped future. As the javadoc suggests, subclassing `SimpleForwardingListenableFuture` will do the job, without introducing potential side-effects on the methods delegated.